# Troubleshooting Service Temporarily Unavailable Error

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.6.1.0

My credit cards authorizations suddenly started failing, which I thought might be the result of me not upgrading - I had version 1.6.1. On upgrading to the latest stable version my admin backend is not accessible, all the site shows is Service Temporarily Unavailable.

I have a backup of the complete site so I can start over, and I do have ssh access now. I'd like to know the best place to start troubleshooting this type of error on upgrade. Any other answers on how to fix my problem appreciated.

Comment: check server errors (apache or nginx error logs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete maintenance.flag from your web root.

Comment: Thank you. This was it. My site is up and broken, but at least I can access it now. Once you gave me this, I found these instructions: https://kb.magenting.com/content/24/89/en/fix-magento-s-error-503-service-temporarily-unavailable.html